# Make 3d gameobject object transparent using slider in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make multiple object transparent using a slider but not all at the same time. What is it ,mean is that the selected object should be able to have a transparent shade on it. I have written a code for it. But I need help to identify my mistake or correct me in the code.
Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TransparentObject : MonoBehaviour  
{
private GameObject objectTotransparent;
public float alpha = 0.5f;
private Material currentMat;
public Slider transparentSlider;

void Awake()
{
    transparentSlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnSliderChanged);
}

//void Start()
//{
    //objectTotransparent = gameObject;
    //currentMat = objectTotransparent.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
//}

void Update()
{
    //ChangeAlpha(currentMat, alpha);
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.current.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        RaycastHit hitObject;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitObject))
        {
            objectTotransparent = hitObject.transform.parent.transform.parent.gameObject;
            objectTotransparent.GetComponent<Recolour>().SetSelected();
        }
    }
}

/*void ChangeAlpha(Material mat, float alphaVal)
{
    
}*/

void OnSliderChanged(float alphaVal)
{
    //ChangeAlpha(currentMat, transparentSlider.value);
    //Color oldColor = mat.color;
    //Color newColor = new Color(oldColor.r, oldColor.g, oldColor.b, alphaVal);
    //mat.SetColor("_Color", newColor);
    transparentSlider = GUI.HorizontalSlider( Rect(20,135,175,30), transparentSlider, 1, 0);
    renderer.material.color.a = transparentSlider;
}

public void Deselect()
{
    objectTotransparent.GetComponent<Recolour>().SetOriginalMaterial();
    objectTotransparent = null;
    transparentSlider.value = alpha;
} 
}
```

Comment: Ok so your slider changed doesn’t get the material. Doesn’t change the alpha  to the alphaval and doesnt set the game object material to the one with the new alpha. So it makes sense it hasn’t changed it

Comment: Yeah correct...

Answer (score 0):

In the `OnSliderChanged` method, try setting the alpha component to `transparentSlider.value` instead of the Slider object. Here's how you should change the transparency of an object in a simple script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeTransparency : MonoBehaviour
{
    //renderer attached to the object that you want to make transparent
    public Renderer rend;
    //ui slider that you want to use to controll the transparency
    public Slider slider;


    private void Update()
    {
        rend.material.color = new Color(
            rend.material.color.r,
            rend.material.color.g,
            rend.material.color.b,
            slider.value
            );       
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** The material that is applied to the object that you want to make transparent should have its Rendering Mode set to Transparent:

Inspector for the material:
[image: Inspector for the material]

Now you can change the albedo and all the other parameters to mimic your original material.

Comment: Still it's not working

Comment: because I have been using shader mode in Legacy Shader/Diffuse